# Oracle ORDS HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: oracle, authentication, curl, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am following this tutorial for Oracle Autonomous database by @ToddSharp : [Microservices The Easy Way With ORDS And Micronaut](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/microservices-the-easy-way-with-ords-and-micronaut-part-1)

Under chapter "Testing your endpoint" I am curl the following:

```
curl -i -k \
--user [client_id]:[client_secret] \
--data "grant_type=client_credentials" \
https://[obfuscated]-demodb.adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/usersvc/oauth/token
```

...with my own credentials.

When doing that I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 24 May 2022 20:19:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Content-Length: 193
Connection: keep-alive


{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/Unauthorized",
    "instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/xxxxxxx"
}%
```

While I do understand the actual error, authorization, after a lot of testing I do not know how to fix it. I have tried for a couple of days now with limited success.

I believe the previous steps have been successful.

I would really appreciate some ideas and tips how to proceed.

**UPDATE**

I have tested a lot but still not sure I know what I am doing and is now curl to try to get some response:

```
curl -i -k \
--user xxxxxx..: yyyyyyy.. \
--data "grant_type=client_credentials" \
https://g9999999999-testdb.adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/usersvc/oauth/token
```

...and get the following response:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ntxNMkxxxxxx4iSRVDqE0w..
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 26 May 2022 22:07:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Content-Length: 182
Connection: keep-alive


{
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Not Found",
"type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/NotFound",
"instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/de999999999437c941e8cf6ffd8e8c"
}
```

Comment: there WAS a bug where this was causing the exact scenario you described - "l_roles(1)   := 'SQL Developer';"  that's been fixed but i'm not sure it's been applied to the Autonomous Cloud environment yet..create a new role/priv for you OAuth2 client , dont' use 'SQL Developer'

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I did redo as you recommended in sqlplus but with the same result

Comment: SQLPlus? I'm suggesting you remove the 'SQL Developer' role from your OAuth2 client and try again.

Comment: First, I have 0% experience of this so I am not sure I am doing the right thing. I have been reading a lot.  I have come so far that I am now curl, see above.

Comment: open your Oauth2 client in the web console. edit it. if you have a 'SQL Developer' role assigned to the client, remove it. Then see if you can get your access token

Comment: I finally succeeded to make this work. THANK YOU @thatjeffsmith! ...now I have another problem.

Comment: I finally succeeded to make this work. THANK YOU @thatjeffsmith!